# How to translate (-Csch[x]^2)^(1/2) to Julia symbolic? ERROR: DomainError with -csch

Tags: julia, symbolic-math

Fyi, Just in case this is a bug in Julia symbolic, added new issue at https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/issues/719

---

I am trying to translate the following. In Mathematica

[image]

In Maple:

[image]

To Julia symbolics. Where `csch` is hyperbolic cosecant function and x is syms.  But Julia gives an error on `(-csch(x)^2)^(1//2)`  but no error on `(csch(x)^2)^(1//2)`

Here is the code

```
>julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.3 (2022-05-06)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  
|__/                   |

julia> using Symbolics

julia> @syms x
(x,)

julia> (-csch(x)^2)^(1//2)
ERROR: DomainError with -1.0:
Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument.
Replace x^y with (x+0im)^y, Complex(x)^y, or similar.
Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_exp_domainerror(x::Float64)
   @ Base.Math ./math.jl:37
 [2] ^
   @ ./math.jl:909 [inlined]
 [3] ^
   @ ./promotion.jl:413 [inlined]
 [4] ^
   @ ./rational.jl:479 [inlined]
 [5] unstable_pow
   @ ~/.julia/packages/SymbolicUtils/qulQp/src/types.jl:801 [inlined]
 [6] ^(a::SymbolicUtils.Mul{Number, Int64, Dict{Any, Number}, Nothing}, b::Rational{Int64})
   @ SymbolicUtils ~/.julia/packages/SymbolicUtils/qulQp/src/types.jl:1047
 [7] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
```

I noticed however that this works

```
julia> sqrt(-csch(x)^2)
sqrt(-(csch(x)^2))
```

But in my case, the exponents are not always `1/2` and so this is not a workaround for me.  For example, I could have `(-csch(x)^2)^(1//3)` and so on. But it is strange that it accepts `sqrt` and not `^(1//2)` in this example.

What exactly is the issue and is there a workaround?

Comment: I assume it's trying to evaluate`(-1)^(1//2) * (csch(x)^2)^(1//2)`. `((-1+0im)*csch(x)^2)^(1//2)` works (not a very elegant solution though...)